# Best practice try/catch throw and XACT_ABORT sql server

Tags: sql-server

I've previously worked with software that generated ETL scripts for us. The scripts have the following structure, but this appears to run contrary to what I've read in msdn. Can anyone offer any thoughts on the following structure?

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY

'DO STUFF'

BEGIN CATCH

SET @return_msg = 'procedure name FAILED'

  + '. Step ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(@v_step,0))

  + '. Error Num: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),0))

  + '. Error Msg: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

  SELECT @return_msg

END CATCH

IF XACT_STATE() <> 0

  BEGIN

   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

  END

  RETURN 0

END
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement effective try catch with xact_state kindly follow [this msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SET XACT_ABORT on

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY

'DO STUFF'
End Try
BEGIN CATCH

SET @return_msg = 'procedure name FAILED'

  + '. Step ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(@v_step,0))

  + '. Error Num: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),0))

  + '. Error Msg: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

  SELECT @return_msg

-- Test XACT_STATE for 0, 1, or -1.  
    -- If 1, the transaction is committable.  
    -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should   
    --     be rolled back.  
    -- XACT_STATE = 0 means there is no transaction and  
    --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.  

    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.  
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +  
              ' Rolling back transaction.'  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END;  

    -- Test whether the transaction is active and valid.  
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT 'The transaction is committable.' +   
              ' Committing transaction.'  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
    END;  

END CATCH

  RETURN 0
```